# How can a user know the browser's keytroke to use accesskey attribute?

Tags: html, accessibility

I would like to have a keyboard shortcuts for my navigation menu items using the solution with accesskey attribute.

Each browser has it's own implementation of how to use accesskey (Alt+Shift, Crtl, Alt...)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key

I would like to inform a user that there are access keys available by putting the exact keystroke combination in parentheses depending on which browser and operating system is being used, for example: Next Page (Alt + N)
As it's suggeted here:
http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey

**Is there some detection javascript code available that would provide a correct accesskey keytroke combination for the specific device that I could display to a user?**

> Keyboard shortcuts are a good idea for software design, and if there were better ways of making keyboard shortcuts available to all users, they would be a great idea for web design too. The accesskey HTML attribute allows web developers to assign certain keyboard shortcuts to web elements. Developers of browsers and assistive technologies implement accesskey support inconsistently and ineffectively. Web developers can still use accesskey to create keyboard shortcuts, but there are many considerations to take into account.

Answer (score 1):

Accesskeys are a rather controversial mechanism. See for example John Foliot's article [The Future of Accesskeys](http://john.foliot.ca/the-future-of-accesskeys/). Accesskeys aren't mentioned in W3C WAI's document [Better Web Browsing: Tips for Customizing Your Computer](https://www.w3.org/WAI/users/browsing).

I am not aware of scripts or mechanism to detect a browser's accesskey keystroke combination. This appears to be something that the user needs to know about their browser. You could try to document these keystrokes for all common browsers and then do browser detection to check what you need to display to the user, but browser detection went out of fashion some time ago.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway I think accesskeys are serving the purpose and can be very useful. Only the implementation is an issue. I guess browser detection script would beed to be made then. I know, not the nicest tsolution

Answer (score 1):

Screen readers will announce the presence & value of the `accesskey` attribute and will also announce the combination needed to access them.

Obviously this does not help keyboard users who are not using screen readers.

Providing an obvious cue to which letter/number to use is often as difficult as providing a way to indicate the keyboard combination for a specific browser. Note that a dedicated keyboard user may already know the combo keys to use, however.

Also, per [the John Foliot article](http://john.foliot.ca/the-future-of-accesskeys/) linked in the previous answer, using `accesskey` has a lot of potential drawbacks. For a quick visual, look at [all the keys JAWS (a screen reader) relies on for users to navigate](http://accessibleweb.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/nvda-keyboard-overlay-1024x689.gif) a page (also embedded below), and consider that it has its own set of key combos too.

[image: Example of which keyboard keys have an assigned use in NVDA]

I recommend you do not use `accesskey`.

However, if you do go ahead with this, you may want to avoid using any letters at all. Years ago (~2002) the UK government came up with a [set of `accesskey` values](http://www.hcidata.co.uk/register-dot-gov-dot-uk-access-key.htm) that use only numbers and map to a specific set of / type of pages:

> S - Skip navigation
>
> 1 - Home page
>
> 2 - What's new
>
> 3 - Site map
>
> 4 - Search
>
> 5 - Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)
>
> 6 - Help
>
> 7 - Complaints procedure
>
> 8 - Terms and conditions
>
> 9 - Feedback form
>
> 0 - Access key details

I had used those on projects with limited success. Limited in that users need to be informed they exist (and must remember them) and success in that they did not conflict with other learned shortcuts at the time..

I stopped using them by around 2010 I think because they just did not otherwise offer any benefit.

To restate, I recommend you do not use `accesskey`. Particularly if you are not a screen reader user or dedicated keyboard user and/or cannot test with those users.

Comment: Very useful info! It's a pity though that accesskeys are not standardized better. Thank you.

Comment: Thought if you don't conflict with the screen reader I don't see why you wouldn't have accesskeys? Who would mind...

Comment: It is less about who would mind and more about how would you make them discoverable, especially to non-SR users. For more in-depth discussion, check out this post by an accessibility consultant and screen reader user: [Time to revisit accesskey?](http://tink.uk/time-to-revisit-accesskey/)

Comment: I've seen the posts but also I'd be interested to see a research results with actual users. I'd say it's discussable. In my opinion particularly useful for SR users, and standard users of course wouldn't be aware of them, at least not in a standardized way e.g. each page would have it's own way - you have the point there. What do we miss here is universal keyboard keystroke the same within all HTML5 browsers, and universal way of notifying users about it directly by the browser e.g. in the address bar can be icon that you can click for the list, similar to bookmark star, cookies notification.

Comment: @HrvojeGolcic I agree that there is value in a universal set of keystrokes and that it can benefit lots of users. I do not know of any research off the top of my head, but I think that is something you can also try to spin up for your own users and see what you find. Then report to the web, WAI, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to have encountered this discussion because I am starting a project that needs a solution. My idea is this: Use "back to top" links in the page with  aria-label instructions that this moves the focus to menu start (or just before it). It's not as efficient as good key combinations, but it is a feature with which users are familiar. Feedback?

Comment: I'm wondering how would this solution looks like in specific? Which aria label would you use and how would you provide the instructions? Also screen reader user uses the keyboard button "home" or "page up", for them it's not really needed in my opinion. What is needed is definitely an implementation of "jump to the main content". If implemented correctly this is a must!